# When I log out and then click a link on Stack Overflow, I am directly signed in

Tags: support, stack-overflow, logout

When I log out and then click on a link on Stack Overflow, I am directly signed in. How does this happen?

When I switch to a different browser (e.g. log in and out in Mozilla, then open IE), then I am asked for my credentials. Why does this happen?

What to do to log out permanently, and not be signed in again in the same browser without having to enter my credentials?

Comment: saved cookies...

Comment: @juergen d Why the cookies are not clear at logout button?Is there any reason?

Comment: I think the scripts that work on log out button  is server side, on other hand deleting cookies is a browser facility, it should be only done by user permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After clicking on *log out* link they redirect us to the [logout page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout) and ask us to confirm that the log out will clear our cookies and log out us on all devices.

Do you actually click on <kbd>Log Out</kbd> button on the redirected page? Because if we don't click on Log Out it won't log out us.

> [image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear your cache and delete cookies, so that neither server nor client machine remember your login details. 
So if don't want automatic login problem then first click on logout and wait while stack exchange deletes your login credentials and then open your web browser settings and clear your cache and delete saved passwords or cookies.

Comment: No; you do not need to clear cache and delete cookies just to log out of the site.

Comment: sometimes it has occurred to me mainly when i am using stackoverflow site in opera mini browser in android phone.I think stackoverflow site developers should work hard to remove bugs in authentication process.stackoverflow developer guys please debug the bugs in authentication process as i have a hard time to authenticate mainly creating career profile.