# Shorter logout process?

Tags: feature-request, logout

When I hover the mouse over my profile name on the top of the screen, I'm shown links for activity, privileges and log out.
On clicking log out, is there really a need to take me to another page where I have to click the log out button?
Couldn't I directly be logged out?

Comment: [That's Not a Bug, it's a Feature Request ;)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40925/212576)

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/do-not-ask-for-confirmation-on-logout?rq=1

Comment: This should be implemented. Because [sometimes users go away (close the tab) just after clicking log out from the top bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180639/187824).